# WebDav authentication and ajaxfilebrowser

Tags: webdav

I'm trying http://www.webdavsystem.com/ajaxfilebrowser on Windows server 2012 and IIS 8.0.
I'm using WebDAV with anonymous access but my server require authentication when I try to Upload, delete etc...
Is there any way to bypass authentication?